# How can I add a vue component in kendo grid custom editor?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, editor

I have a column of kendo grid like:

```
<kendo-grid-column
    :field="'qrcode'"
    :title="'qrcode'"
    :width="200"
    :editor="qrcodeEditor"
></kendo-grid-column>
```

According to [Setting Custom Editors](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/editing/#toc-setting-custom-editors), I can rewrite the editor to `textarea`, `checkbox`, or `dropdown list`, like

```
textareaEditor: function(container, options) {
    $('<textarea data-bind="value: ' +
            options.field +
            '" cols="20" rows="4"></textarea>'
    ).appendTo(container);
},
```

My problem is what if the editor is a vue component, like [<qrcode-capture />](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```js
methods:{
    qrcodeEditor: function(container, options) {
        // An <input> element is required for binding data
        let input = $(`<input data-bind="value:${options.field}" class="k-textbox width-50"/>`);
        input.appendTo(container);

        // use Vue.extend to make a component constructor, and new a component
        let qrcodeCapture = new (Vue.extend(QrcodeCapture))();
        qrcodeCapture.$on("decode", decodedString => {
            input.val(decodedString).trigger("change");
            // Trigger "change" element to tell kendo that you have change the data
        });
        qrcodeCapture.$mount();
        container.append(qrcodeCapture.$el);
    },
}
```